# [ERROR] : Called wait_for_result when no goal exists

Tags: ros, navigation, rospy, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is terminal output:

```
[ERROR] [1660043302.501132, 4595.399000]: Called wait_for_result when no goal exists

[INFO] [1660043302.505849, 4595.405000]: Goal execution done!
```

It says Goal execution done but robot is not moving.

Can someone help me please?

```
from unittest import result
import rospy
import actionlib
from move_base_msgs.msg import MoveBaseAction, MoveBaseGoal

class SendGoal():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = actionlib.SimpleActionClient('move_base',MoveBaseAction)
        self.wait = self.client.wait_for_result()

        self.goal = MoveBaseGoal()
        self.goal.target_pose.header.frame_id = "map"
        self.goal.target_pose.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 30.0
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.orientation.w = 0.01
        self.goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = -10.5

    def movebase_client(self):
        
        self.client.wait_for_server()

        self.client.send_goal(self.goal)
        
        if result:
            print("job done")
        if not self.wait:
            rospy.logerr("Action server not available!")
            rospy.signal_shutdown("Action server not available!")
        else:
            return self.client.get_result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        rospy.init_node('movebase_client_py')
        result = SendGoal().movebase_client()
        if result:
            rospy.loginfo("Goal execution done!")
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        rospy.loginfo("Navigation test finished.")
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404822/%5Berror%5D-:-called-wait_for_result-when-no-goal-exists/) by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Onurcan

You are trying to wait  result before sending goal to action server. In here

```
self.wait = self.client.wait_for_result()
```

You should do that after sending goal

```
self.client.send_goal(self.goal)
self.wait = self.client.wait_for_result()
```

and **use self.client.wait_for_result() return** for result variable.

In the class init you can use client.wait_for_server() function to wait for server.

---

Originally posted by [muratcngncr](https://answers.ros.org/users/113382/muratcngncr/) with karma: 56 on 2022-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on 2022-08-09**:
Yeah i realized after i posted it but thanks a lot.  :)